# A question about continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $f:I\to R$ is differentiable and $f'$ ascending (or descending), then $f'$ is continuous ( $I$ is an interval and $R$ the real number). Is the above statement true whenever $f'$ is one to one?

Comment: How do you solve the problem when $f'$ is monotone?

Comment: It is a corollary of a Theorem

Comment: I'm a bit surprised by the downvote. The problem seems to range from very easy to tricky depending on what the OP knows about everywhere differentiable functions.

Comment: @aliakbar: What theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, thanks to the middle value property of the derivative - namely that $f^\prime \restriction_{[x,y]}$ attends every value between $f^\prime(x)$ and $f^\prime(y)$. The property itself is an easy exercise.

Comment: How do you deduce the continuity of $ f' $ from the fact that it has the Intermediate Value Property? There are discontinuous functions that possess this property.

Comment: I did not downvote you, by the way. I just wanted to say that I don’t see the implication right away.

Comment: @HaskellCurry: Sure, but together with injectivity this implies that $f^\prime$ is monotone.

Comment: Monotonicity implies continuity, that’s for sure as it is guaranteed by the Intermediate Value Property. However, how injectivity implies monotonicity is something that I fail to see. I hope you don’t mind my being a little fussy over the facts. :)

Comment: @Haskell: Here are some proofs that injective functions with IVP are continuous: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7172/injective-functions-with-intermediate-value-property-are-continuous-better-proo. (Although in some of them it is taken for granted that it is straightforward to show that an injective function with IVP is monotone.)

Comment: Alright! I see it now. +1 for your answer. :)